# Display images sizes in Wordpress Media Uploader (3.5)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, media, uploader

This is the javascript I am using:

```
    media.frame = wp.media({
        title: "Choose Image",
        button: {
            text: "Pick Image"
        },
        multiple: false
    });
```

Everything is fine but I can't seem to find a way to display the images sizes except if I set the frame to "post".

So the question is how to display the "Attachment Display Settings" section.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this WordPress filter to the filter hook `image_size_names_choose` which outputs the list of available image sizes to choose from.

Source : http://www.limecanvas.com/adding-custom-image-sizes-to-wordpress-3-5-media-manager/

Comment: No, doesn't seem to do the job. I want to display the default sizes, not to make modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Once Gone through this once and found something on codecanyon.. Try the link

http://codecanyon.net/forums/thread/wordpress-35-media-uploader-api/83117

might solve it